# Why is this sql query not working when then function that queries is in another file?

Tags: python, sqlite, rest, flask

I'm writing an api endpoint using flask. I have created a database using SQLite called `BE.db` and have a table in it called `result`. I have written a function called `getResultData` which is like this:

```
import sqlite3

def getResultData(seat_no):
  conn = sqlite3.connect("BE.db")
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  data = cursor.execute("select * from result where seat_no = ?;",(seat_no,))
  for row in data:
    output = {
      "Seat No": row[0],
      "PRN": row[1],
      "Location": row[2],
      "Total Gradepoint": row[3],
      "SGPI": row[4],
      "Status": row[5],
      "Year of Admission": row[6],
      "College ID": row[7],
      "Gender": row[8]
    }
  conn.close()
  return output
```

This function is stored in a file called utils.py When I call this function by itself it works fine and returns the proper values. But when i call it from the flask app.py file it gives this error

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

But when i copy paste the exact function in the app.py file it works.
Here is the app.py file without pasting the getResultData function in it.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import utils

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

@app.route('/getResultData', methods=['POST'])
def getResultData():
  body = request.get_json()
  output = utils.getResultData(request.get_json(body['seat_no']))
  return jsonify(output)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81)
```

This is the curl command i'm using to get the response.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "seat_no": 5201543
}' http://localhost:81/getResultData
```

I tried to use f string and string formatting instead of passing parameters but then it gives an error stating unidentified character '{'. How can i get it to work as if the function was in app.py

Comment: You use `request.get_json` twice and the second time in a wrong way so that `seat_no` parameter of `utils.getResultData` becomes a dictionary instead of a number. See https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Request.get_json.html